# Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /opt/.../wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have been following this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-your-plugins-in-github-with-automatic-updates--wp-34817) to deploy a WordPress plugin through Github. After setting up everything.
I get an error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /opt/.../wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 621
```

In the plugin infobox. What could I be doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$response->name = $this->pluginData["Name"];` to function `setPluginInfo`. I think you could remove `$response->plugin_name...`. Perhaps there was a change since that guide was written back in 2014.

Comment: I do not, sorry.